# php : unable to upload file to the server

Tags: php

hey I am not much of a PHP coder

I am using following to upload file to server acn any body help me whats wrong with this code

```
<?php 

$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://iphone.zcentric.com/uploads/{$file}";
}

?>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Would you tell us what happens when you run that code? Is the ./uploads/ directory existing *and* writable? Does $_FILES['userfile'] exist when the code is run? Is there any PHP error being reported? PS: I don't think basename() is necessary.

Comment: yes I am getting a PHP errors

Comment: Paste them in your question, all of them exactly as they appear. And verify ./uploads/ directory is writable by writing a text file with PHP into that directory. I bet we can solve this if you collaborate with us! :)

Comment: It's useless asking for more info while we don't see the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the PHP code, though without an error it is difficult to tell what is happening.

Somethings which could cause uploads not to work, and which may not return errors:

1. Ensure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data` in the form tag:

   `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">`
2. Make sure PHP is accepting the input, by adjusting the following PHP ini variables:

   > http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
   >   http://us.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time
   >   http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize
3. Finally, ensure that permissions are properly set for both the temp upload folder (http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) and the folder you are moving files to.  If it is a Windows server you might also run into an inheritance issue which will require you to change the default upload directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
iF YOU WANT TO UPLOAD .pdf FILE TO LOCAL SERVER THEN USE THIS SIMPLE METHOD, Lets we are doing code here under Button Click Event...


if (isset($_POST['submit']))  
{

if ( ($_FILES["file"]["type"] =="application/pdf"))
{ 

if (file_exists("C:/xampplite/htdocs/site/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))

    echo " This File is already exists in folder";
 else
{
  move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"C:/xampplite/htdocs/site/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);      
  echo "File have been Stored in:-C:/xampplite/htdocs/site/upload/ "  . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

  }
}

}//end of click_event
```

Comment: this is an incredible, your solution is very handy !

Answer (score 0):

could u pls publish what the error u get?Your code looks ok.Here the upload folder must he stay in the upper of the directory where you run the code.Then it should to work.if your script folder like this /test/script/abc.php then your uploads directory should be /test/uploads.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" multiple="">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
upload.php
<?php
//$target_dir = "uploads/";
/*$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
*/


if(count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']) > 0)
{

         $i=0;
         while($i<count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])) 
         {
          $filen = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]['name']["$i"]; 
          $path = 'uploads/'.$filen;
          $imageFileType = pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          if (file_exists($path)) {
           echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
           }else  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
           && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
           echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";

          }

               else if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']["$i"],$path)) 
               {
               //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]["$i"]). " has been uploaded.";
               $files=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]["$i"];
               echo $files;?><img src="<?php echo $path;?>" style="width:200px;height:200px" alt="" >
               <?php
               } 
               $i++;
          }



}
?>
```