# Dynamically created input type=file is not submiting

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

Actually when i create dynamically a new input field whose type is file using jquery and submit it it don't send any thing on the receiving side. Please help me in this

This is jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add').click(function(){
    var str = '<input type="file" name="file[]">';
    $('#file').append(str);
});
});
```

This is HTML code

```
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<form id="" action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="file"> 
        <input type="file" name="file[]">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is PHP code

```
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_POST);
```

And this is php out put
    [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB5ZO.png)

Comment: please post the output

Comment: When you do `var_dump($_FILES);` what is the output?

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: This is actuall output http://prntscr.com/8pd0wo

Comment: See my above comment and edit your question and add your output there.

Comment: Have you browse some file to your code?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884631/php-unable-to-upload-file-to-the-server